# Appending custom ship options in Magento block

Tags: php, magento

I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-shipping-method) to create a custom shipping method for my Magento install.  The only problem I'm having is adding additional special options to the shipping method on front-end.  For instance.

[image: Shipping Method]

The "Ground" Method with UPS Freight is my custom method.  Off the side or below it I'd like to add two checkboxes, one for "Lift Gate" and another for "Residential".  I think I need to override a block somewhere, but I'm not really sure where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magento shipping API does not offer to add additional options to shipping methods. It can be done, but it requires template changes and more, so it's usually not the best way to follow.
Instead it is recommended to add two shipping methods to your carrier, so you get (for example)

**Ground**
[ ] UPS Freight (Lift Gate) **$815.51**
[ ] UPS Freight (Residential) **$815.51**
**Customer Pickup**
[ ] Arranged **$0.00**

To do so, simply adjust the method title in the first `shipping/rate_result_method` add a second  instance with the second option to your returned result object.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to add a second instance with the second object.  I tried adding and "allowed_methods" option to my config.xml, but there isn't a way to display it on the back-end, and it doesn't show up on the front end.  Could you clarify or go in to a little more detail?  Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it figured out.  I needed to add a function called "toOptionsArray" in my model for the back-end, and the modify the getAllowedMethods function for the front-end.